# Selenium java Date Time validation issue

Tags: java, datetime, selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement where I have to extract the date and time displayed on the screen, which is in following format: `2021 Jul 12 @ 06:30`

And I have to compare this with a specific timezone to check whether they are equal or not.
Can anyone please help me with the way to handle this logic in Selenium Java (any version)?

Comment: Use JSoup better

Comment: How can you compare a date and time to a time zone? Won’t that be like comparing an employee to a product? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are retrieving the date time as a string, you can use a combination of ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTime as follows:

> First we get your system zone and zoned datetime:

```
ZoneId timeZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();

LocalDateTime nowLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime nowZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, timeZone);
```

> Then we define the pattern using formatter, and use it to format the example string to a `ZonedDateTime` object:

```
DateTimeFormatter exampleFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMM dd @ HH:mm");
String example = "2021 Jul 12 @ 06:30";

ZonedDateTime exampleZonedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(example, formatter).atZone(timeZone);
```

> Here, I used the system timezone but you can change this to the zone you like assuming you know the time zone of the example.

This way we can compare `exampleZonedDateTime` with `nowZoned DateTime` where:
`nowZonedDateTime` holds the systems current defined timezone
`exampleZonedDateTime` holds the Zoned date time you want to compare with.

Also you can convert both to `LocalDateTime` objects using `.toLocalDateTime()` method in the `ZonedDateTime` class.

Comment: For getting the current time, do not use `LocalDateTime`. Just use `ZonedDateTime nowZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(timeZone);`. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: True, but I'm trying to illustrate how they relate to each other, since most people are more familiar with LocalDateTime, I believe starting from something that's somewhat familiar can make it easier to receive the concept.